# How to append an array to another array, while keeping both arrays seperate from each other in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays: A and X. X is an array filled with other arrays. I do not have access to X, so I cannot change it in any way. I need A to be filled with certain arrays from X, but I need to maintain the individual nature of the arrays. The code I have thus far looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    if X[i, split] <= n:
         A = np.append(A, X)
```

The issue with this is that, while it does successfully get only the values that I need from X into A, it makes every value a part of one large array, rather than retaining the separate arrays. I have attempted to utilize a matrix here, however, I run into an issue where X is recognized as merely a one dimensional array rather than two dimensional such as a matrix would be.

How might I go about getting the arrays from X into A while still keeping them separated into their own individual arrays? Thanks!

It is possible that I am not asking the right question, but my goal with asking this is to get a shape function run on A to return two values, such as (10, 4). Currently X does this, but once I append the arrays into A, I get only one value that appears like (40,), where it has taken all the correct values, but failed to separate them into their separate arrays.

--
The first few lines of X are displayed as such when printed out:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]

 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]

 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]...
```

When it is appended into A, it instead becomes this:

```
[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 4.9 3.  1.4 0.2 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 ...
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Edited, is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Did you read the `np.append` docs?  Notice the bit about `axis`, and what it does when it isn't specified?  Why are you using `np.append` instead of a list append?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work as you expect it?

```
array2d = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

array = [[x for x in arr if (x % 2 == 0)] for arr in array2d]
```